# SICP exercise 1.28: false negatives in the Miller-Rabin test

Tags: algorithm, scheme, lisp, primes, sicp

> **Exercise 1.28.**  One variant of the Fermat test that cannot be fooled is called the Miller-Rabin test (Miller 1976; Rabin 1980). This
>   starts from an alternate form of Fermat's Little Theorem, which states
>   that if n is a prime number and a is any positive integer less than n,
>   then a raised to the (n - 1)st power is congruent to 1 modulo n. To
>   test the primality of a number n by the Miller-Rabin test, we pick a
>   random number a < n and raise a to the (n - 1)st power modulo n using
>   the expmod procedure. However, whenever we perform the squaring step
>   in expmod, we check to see if we have discovered a ''nontrivial square
>   root of 1 modulo n,'' that is, a number not equal to 1 or n - 1 whose
>   square is equal to 1 modulo n. It is possible to prove that if such a
>   nontrivial square root of 1 exists, then n is not prime. It is also
>   possible to prove that if n is an odd number that is not prime, then,
>   for at least half the numbers a < n, computing a^(n-1) in this way will
>   reveal a nontrivial square root of 1 modulo n. (This is why the
>   Miller-Rabin test cannot be fooled.) Modify the expmod procedure to
>   signal if it discovers a nontrivial square root of 1, and use this to
>   implement the Miller-Rabin test with a procedure analogous to
>   fermat-test. Check your procedure by testing various known primes and
>   non-primes. Hint: One convenient way to make expmod signal is to have
>   it return 0.

```
(define (fast-prime? n)
  (define (fast-prime-iter n counter)
    (cond ((= counter 1) #t) ; There is no need to check 1
          ((miller-rabin-test n counter)
           (fast-prime-iter n (- counter 1)))
          (else 
            (newline)
            (display counter)
            #f)))
  (fast-prime-iter n (- n 2)))

(define (miller-rabin-test n a)
  (define (expmod base exp m)
    (cond ((= exp 0) 1)
          ((even? exp)
           (nontrivial-square-root?
             (remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m))
                        m)))
          (else
            (remainder (* base (expmod base (- exp 1) m))
                       m))))
  (= (expmod a (- n 1) n) 1))

(define (nontrivial-square-root? val)
  (if (= val 1)
    0
    val))
```

My idea is to filter out those so-called "nontrivial square roots of 1 modulo n" with the procedure `nontrivial-square-root?`. A `0` is returned if `(remainder (square (expmod base (/ exp 2) m)) m)` is 1, in which case the square of `(expmod base (/ exp 2) m)` must be equal to 1 modulo n (this is because `m` always equals `n`), making it a nontrivial square root.

While `nontrivial-square-root?` does filter out carmichael numbers such as 561, 1105, 1729, 2465, 2821 and 6601, prime numbers such as 7 and 13 are also reported to be composite.

What causes these false negatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part of the quote marked with bold text:

> However, whenever we perform the squaring step in expmod, we check to see if we have discovered a ''nontrivial square root of 1 modulo n,'' that is, a number  **not equal to 1 or n - 1**  whose square is equal to 1 modulo n

So before you square and take the remainder you have to check that the argument is not 1 or n - 1. This occurs, e.g., if you call `(miller-rabin-test 5 3)`.  Working the recursion out you notice that there is  a call `(nontrivial-square-root? (remainder (square 4) 5))` which evaluates to `(nontrivial-square-root? 1)`. However, 5 can still be prime because 4 is 5 - 1.

So in the squaring part you can, e.g., call a following function:

```
(define (sqrmod-with-check val n)
  (let ((sqrmod (remainder (square val) n)))
    (cond ((or (= val (- n 1)) (= val 1)) sqrmod)
          ((= sqrmod 1) 0)
          (else sqrmod))))
```

where the arguments are the `expmod` call and `m`. This does the square and remainder for you except in the case we have found a nontrivial square root of 1 modulo n, when it returns 0. I divided it to three conditions, instead of two, just because of readability.

Comment: "whose square is equal to 1 modulo n"...

Why is this checked by:
 ```(= 1 (remainder (square val) n))``` 
instead of:
 ```(= (square val) (remainder 1 n)```
?

Comment: @randbw the sentence square is equal to 1 modulo n, is a bit cryptic, but it basically means that you take the module of both n^2 and 1, and compare them. However if n>1 the (remainder 1 n) is always 1.

Comment: Thanks for explaining!